# arithmetic in Prolog

Tags: prolog, clpfd

If I have

```
A in 0..4, A * A #=A.
```

Is it possible that

```
A in 0..1.
```

?

I would say no because 0*0 = 0, and 1*1 = 1, so these two can not be A?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: But these two can be A.

Comment: Why do you think it could not while it satisfies all the contraints?

Comment: and please stay on your first question, no need to create many of them

Comment: nice question, about identity...

Comment: I think Markus Triska (author of SWI-Prolog CLP(FD)) could have posted about this in SWI-Prolog mailing list, some month ago... not sure it's relevant. Try searching the mailing list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are asking here is about the consistency of CLPFD-systems. Generally speaking, systems try to maintain consistency "as good as they can" with different kinds of tradeoff to consistency vs. speed. But most of the time they deliver only safe approximations. In this case, however, everything seems perfect (here using SICStus):

```
?- A in 0..4, A * A #=A.
   clpfd:(A*A#=A), A in 0..1.
```

So, we get as an answer: Yes, there are solutions, provided `clpfd(:A*A#=A), A in 0..1` is true. *A priori* we cannot say whether or not that is the case, but we might try it out:

```
?- A in 0..4, A * A #=A, A = 1.
   A = 1.
?- A in 0..4, A * A #=A, A = 0.
   A = 0.
```

So: Both 0 and 1 are a solution, and  thus `A in 0..1` is a perfect answer!

BTW, you get (essentially) the same answer in SICStus, SWI, B, and GNU.