# Is z3 the most efficient solver for quantifier-free integer propositional logic?

Tags: prolog, logic, z3, cplex, smt

Sorry that this question is subjective, but given that the Stack Overflow has the largest Z3 user base, I want to give it a try.

I have a big constraint satisfaction problem that consists of many integer propositional logic formulas and a few first order logic formulas that only contain integers(quantifiers). I care very much about the efficiency, because I am building an interactive program synthesizer.

I am now using z3 solver and the check time is sometimes too long. I wonder if z3 is the best tool to tackle the problem I mentioned in above or there is a better tool? How about CPLEX?

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

**Edit:**

Sorry, the code has been remove for privacy reason. I can email you my code personally if you are willing to take a look. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post an example of the problem that currently takes too long with Z3, so we can compare alternatives for your use case.

Comment: did you tried [quacode](http://quacode.barichard.com/) ?

Comment: @mat I just posted my code. Thanks.

Comment: You sure you are seeking quantifier free "integers" solver. Strictly speaking a solver that says yes or no always, doesn't exists. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation#Hilbert.27s_tenth_problem If you were fine with bounded domains you could try CLP(FD) as well.

Comment: In my experience, z3 performs better than Gurobi (the ILP solver) in my big Integer Linear Problem. You can see the slightly better performance of gurobi vs CPLEX in their own report like http://www.gurobi.com/pdfs/benchmarks.pdf . The users mostly believe that Gurobi and CPLEX show same performance. Therefore, I think Z3 would be better than CPLEX too.